# How to allow a rest resource for logged in user only

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have following projection

```
@Projection(name="detail",types={Letter.class})
public interface LetterDetailProjection {

    Integer getLetterId();
    Date getInitiationDate();
    Date getMaxResponseDate();
    String getComments();
    boolean isActive();
    Set<RecipientLetterProjection> getRecipients();
    Set<LetterDocumentMinProjection> getUploadedDocuments();
}
```

Letter class has a user object. how do i use this projection so that it returns only those letters which have 'user' equal to logged in user?

Comment: You scan solve that with an custom Query of the findAll() method.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using @Query and Spel as follows and its working:

```
public interface LetterRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Letter, Integer> {
    @Override
    @Query("select l from Letter l where l.sender.appUserName = ?#{principal.username}")
    Page findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

for more details visit https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions